# How can I move the object back to his parent position as child?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
IEnumerator ThrowObject(Transform objectToMove, Transform toPosition, float duration)
    {
        Vector3 originPos = objectToMove.position;

        float counter = 0;

        while (counter < duration)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            Vector3 currentPos = objectToMove.position;

            float time = Vector3.Distance(currentPos, toPosition.position) / (duration - counter) * Time.deltaTime;

            objectToMove.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(currentPos, toPosition.position, time);

            yield return null;
        }
        
        var naviParent = GameObject.Find("Navi Parent");
        StartCoroutine(ThrowBack(objectToMove, naviParent.transform.position , duration));
    }

    IEnumerator ThrowBack(Transform objectToMove,Vector3 originalPosition , float duration)
    {
        float counter = 0;

        while (counter < duration)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            Vector3 currentPos = objectToMove.position;

            float time = Vector3.Distance(currentPos, originalPosition) / (duration - counter) * Time.deltaTime;

            objectToMove.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(currentPos, originalPosition, time);
            //yield return null essentially means "return here every frame"
            yield return null;
        }
    }
```

When the game start NAVI is child of Navi Parent. Navi Parent position is set to 0,0,0

[image: Navi Parent is at position 0,0,0]

Also NAVI is at position 0,0,0

[image: NAVI is child of Navi Parent and NAVI is also at position 0,0,0]

Now NAVI is start moving to the target in the method ThrowObject and when NAVI reached the target a new Coroutine start and NAVI is moving back to his parent :

```
var naviParent = GameObject.Find("Navi Parent");
```

But when NAVI is reaching to Navi Parent back his position is not at 0,0,0 :
You can see NAVI is not back to the Navi Parent(The player hand) but he is back close to it.

[image: Close near the player hand Navi Parent]

Now NAVI position is : X 0.002350773   Y  0.0007914092   Z 0.002649077

And if I change it on my own the NAVI position to 0,0,0 now NAVI is in the player hand as it should be :

[image: NAVI is at 0,0,0 as it should be but I changed it]

I want that when the NAVI is moving back in the ThrowBack that he will end at 0,0,0 and not that I will have to change it back to 0,0,0

And if I will change NAVI in the end after the second Coroutine ends it will looks like navi change position like jumping or changing position rude and I want it to move smooth back to 0,0,0 in the while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your issue is with:

```
float time = Vector3.Distance(currentPos, originalPosition) / (duration - counter) * Time.deltaTime;

objectToMove.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(currentPos, originalPosition, time);
```

You are evaluating the `currentPos` every frame which then decreases `time`, eventually, due to also applying `deltaTime`, this `time` gets very small as it approaches the destination.

`MoveTowards`' third parameter is a `maxDistanceDelta`, which I assume is what you're trying to use `time` for, variable name notwithstanding.  However, it is intended as a *max speed* limiter.

Try replacing the above two lones of code with:

```
objectToMove.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(currentPos, originalPosition, Speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Or, at the very least, let `time` be no less than some small positive value (eg, `time = Mathf.Max(time, 0.001f)`)

Comment: The objectToMove return to the parent but then when I'm moving the player the objectToMove stay behind and move randomly and not moving with the player and the objectToMove is child of the parent and set to 0,0,0 but still is not moving correctly with the player not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

I think it happens because of your counter. Sometimes counter gets a bigger value than the duration and that might effect the calculations. Also using [Vectore.Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) is better. Check this out and see if your problem gets fixed.

```
private IEnumerator ThrowObject(Transform objectToMove, Transform toPosition, float duration)
{
    Vector3 originPos = objectToMove.position;
    float counter = 0;
    while (objectToMove.position != toPosition.position)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        if(counter > duration)
        {
            counter = duration;
        }
        objectToMove.position = Vector3.Lerp(originPos, toPosition.position, counter / duration);
        yield return null;
    }
    var naviParent = GameObject.Find("Navi Parent");
    StartCoroutine(ThrowBack(objectToMove, naviParent.transform.position, duration));
}

private IEnumerator ThrowBack(Transform objectToMove, Vector3 originalPosition, float duration)
{
    Vector3 originPos = objectToMove.position;
    float counter = 0;
    while (objectToMove.position != originalPosition)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        if (counter > duration)
        {
            counter = duration;
        }
        objectToMove.position = Vector3.Lerp(originPos, originalPosition, counter / duration);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that you are trying to move the object back to the parent with a set time no matter the distance.

If I'm right the method you should use is this.

```
float duration = 1f;
float time = 0f;

while (time < 1)
{
    time += Time.deltaTime / duration;
    object.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(object.localPosition, targetPosition, time);
    yield return null;
}
```

That will move an object to a new position with a set duration.